# CoreData Persistent Store Seemingly Empty

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nspersistentstore

First I'll give a bit of background on what I'm working on. I'm creating a CRUD iOS application that gets information from an API we've created. Once I have pulled down the data I store it with CoreData. I then use an NSFetchedResultsController to display this data in a table view. Problem is that when I show a modal view on top of the table view and then dismiss the modal view, the table is cleared and everything short of re-downloading the data and inserting it again doesn't work.

The problem arises though when I'm pulling fresh data from the API. Using trial and error I have narrowed down the problem to where I delete all the old data in the persistent store (I have two stores, one for user created data and one for data from other users). This code snippet is from the API call where I handle fetching data:

```
    [self deleteAllEntitiesNamed:@"Object"];
    [self parseResponseObjectIntoManagedObjects:[response results] inStoreWithURL:storeURL];
    success(response);
```

The `[self deleteAllEntitiesNamed:@"Object"];` call goes into the store for other users and deletes all Object entities with the following code:

```
    NSArray *result = [self performFetchRequestForEntityNamed:entity inStoreWithURL:url];

    for(id r in result)
    {
        [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:r];
    }
```

I have traced the problem down to this function call. If I comment out the delete call in the API handler, there is no problem maintaining the table between views, though it has the bad side effect of duplicating a lot of the data already in the store. I feel I may be missing something about deleting items in the store, though it makes no sense to me as I re-insert the data immediately after deleting the old store.

I have tried deleting and re-initializing the entire store, but then no data loads at all.

Thanks ahead of time for any insight available.

EDIT: I should also add that when I have tried to pull out objects from the store after moving back to the table view, I get an empty result using the same fetch request that succeeds at getting Objects out of the store immediately after I finish the API call in my success callback.

Comment: When are you fetching the data? For example, viewWill/didAppear etc is called on the presenting view controller when a modal view is dismissed, could this be the problem?

Comment: You should implement the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate protocol and update your table view in these callbacks which will be called when the object graph changes. -- Also you should consider an incremental approach rather than deleting and re-creating entities.

Comment: In the first code snippet, I have a success callback. In that callback in my view I do a fetch request to get the just fetched objects. And I was planning a incremental approach like suggested, but due to time constraints I need to use this approach for this version of the application.